# How to connect Oracle 11g XE installed on Docker on mac M1 in Qt

Tags: oracle, docker, qt, qt-creator, apple-m1

What should i put inside the quotation marks?

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("");
```

I have tried putting "QODBC" as windows owners did but it didn't work.

Comment: have you tried QOCI ?

Comment: Yeah, I did. I got this error: "QSqlDatabase: QOCI driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QODBC QPSQL
QSqlQuery::exec: database not open"

Comment: https://github.com/thecodemonkey86/qt_oci_driver